# CoreText Framework - App Won't Run in Simulator - iOS

Tags: objective-c, xcode, frameworks, ios-simulator, core-text

I have an app which uses the CoreText framework. I am able to run the app successfully on the iPhone and iPad 1 and 2.

However I am unable to run the app in the xCode iPhone / iPad simulator. I am getting the following error message :

ld: warning: ignoring file /Users/croydonbod/Documents/iDevelopment/MyApp/CoreText.framework/CoreText, file was built for unsupported file format which is not the architecture being linked (i386)

Undefined symbols for architecture i386:
  "_CTFontCreateWithName", referenced from:
      -[View drawRect:] in View.o
  "_CTFramesetterCreateWithAttributedString", referenced from:
      -[View drawRect:] in View.o
  "_CTFramesetterCreateFrame", referenced from:
      -[View drawRect:] in View.o
  "_CTFrameGetVisibleStringRange", referenced from:
      -[View drawRect:] in View.o
  "_CTFrameDraw", referenced from:
      -[View drawRect:] in View.o
  "_kCTFontAttributeName", referenced from:
      -[View drawRect:] in View.o
  "_kCTForegroundColorAttributeName", referenced from:
      -[View drawRect:] in View.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture i386
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

Can anyone suggest why this is happening ?

Thank you.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

it looks like you *copied* the CoreText framework files from the SDK into your app instead of weak-linking the framework (which means the appropriate framework would load correctly for the device or for the simulator).

Delete the CoreText framework from your project and re-add it, making sure to ***uncheck*** the "Copy items to destination folder" checkbox if it appears and once the CoreText framework is added, make certain the "Relative to SDK" Location is set for the CoreText framework in your project.  Here is how it's set for the UIKit framework:

[image]

Comment: Thanks - I deleted out the CoreText files and then re-linked. Now for some reason the app wont compile on a device or the simulator. On the device I now get :

Comment: Undefined symbols for architecture armv7:
  "_CGContextTranslateCTM", referenced from:
      -[View drawRect:] in View.o
  "_CGPathRelease", referenced from:
      -[View drawRect:] in View.o
  "_CGContextSetTextMatrix", referenced from:
      -[View drawRect:] in View.o
  "_CGPathAddRect", referenced from:
      -[View drawRect:] in View.o
  "_CGAffineTransformIdentity", referenced from:
      -[View drawRect:] in View.o
  "_CGContextScaleCTM", referenced from:
      -[View drawRect:] in View.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture armv7

Comment: clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

Comment: Ah it's Core Graphics. Added it in and it works. Thank you for your help - well spotted. Really odd - how on earth was it compiling with Core Graphics before ?!